# Add image into a word .docx document header using POI XWPF

Tags: java, apache-poi

I've been trying to add .png image to .docx file header with Apache POI. I did´t find a method that help me. someone know how do it?
Whith this code I could add only text.

```
XWPFDocument docc = new XWPFDocument(); 
CTP ctpHeader = CTP.Factory.newInstance(); 
CTR ctrHeader = ctpHeader.addNewR(); 
CTText ctHeader = ctrHeader.addNewT(); 
String headerText = "mi encabezado"; 
ctHeader.setStringValue(headerText); 

XWPFParagraph headerParagraph = new XWPFParagraph(ctpHeader, docc); XWPFParagraph[] parsHeader = new XWPFParagraph[1]; 
parsHeader[0] = headerParagraph; header.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, parsHeader);
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and explain what "doesn't work" exactly means.

Comment: I had tried with this code but didn't found a method that help me. I could add only text

Comment: XWPFDocument docc = new XWPFDocument();
            CTP ctpHeader = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
         CTR ctrHeader = ctpHeader.addNewR();
   CTText ctHeader = ctrHeader.addNewT();
   String headerText = "mi encabezado";
   ctHeader.setStringValue(headerText);
   
   
   XWPFParagraph headerParagraph = new XWPFParagraph(ctpHeader, docc);
         XWPFParagraph[] parsHeader = new XWPFParagraph[1];
         parsHeader[0] = headerParagraph;
         header.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, parsHeader);

Comment: Please don't show code in comments. You can edit your question and show the code there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Example for creating a `Word` document with header and footer and an image in the header:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.model.XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTabStop;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTabJc;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordHeaderFooter {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  // the body content
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body:");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum....");

  // create header start
  CTSectPr sectPr = doc.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
  XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(doc, sectPr);

  XWPFHeader header = headerFooterPolicy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = header.getParagraphArray(0);
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);

  CTTabStop tabStop = paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewTabs().addNewTab();
  tabStop.setVal(STTabJc.RIGHT);
  int twipsPerInch =  1440;
  tabStop.setPos(BigInteger.valueOf(6 * twipsPerInch));

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Header:");
  run.addTab();

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  String imgFile="Koala.png";
  run.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFile), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile, Units.toEMU(50), Units.toEMU(50));


  // create footer start
  XWPFFooter footer = headerFooterPolicy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = footer.getParagraphArray(0);
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Footer:");


  doc.write(new FileOutputStream("test.docx"));

 }
}
```

**Edit Mar 29 2016:**

This had worked until apache poi 3.13. Now with 3.14 it works not more. Reason: POI will not save the blip reference for images in header paragraphs anymore.

`/word/header1.xml`:

Code compiled and run with 3.13:

```
...
<pic:blipFill><a:blip r:embed="rId1"/>
...
```

Same code compiled and run with 3.14:

```
...
<pic:blipFill><a:blip r:embed=""/>
...
```

**Edit Mar 31 2016:**

Found the problem. Someone was the opinion the `public final PackageRelationship getPackageRelationship()` needs to be deprecated. So in `XWPFRun.java` the code in `public XWPFPicture addPicture(...)` was changed

from version 3.13:

```
...
            CTBlipFillProperties blipFill = pic.addNewBlipFill();
            CTBlip blip = blipFill.addNewBlip();
            blip.setEmbed(picData.getPackageRelationship().getId());
...
```

to version 3.14:

```
...
            CTBlipFillProperties blipFill = pic.addNewBlipFill();
            CTBlip blip = blipFill.addNewBlip();
            blip.setEmbed(parent.getDocument().getRelationId(picData));
...
```

But `parent.getDocument()` is the `XWPFDocument` always while the `picData` possible is related to the `XWPFHeaderFooter`.

At the beginning of the `public XWPFPicture addPicture(...)` the programmers have already know this.

```
...
        if (parent.getPart() instanceof XWPFHeaderFooter) {
            XWPFHeaderFooter headerFooter = (XWPFHeaderFooter)parent.getPart();
            relationId = headerFooter.addPictureData(pictureData, pictureType);
            picData = (XWPFPictureData) headerFooter.getRelationById(relationId);
        } else {
            XWPFDocument doc = parent.getDocument();
            relationId = doc.addPictureData(pictureData, pictureType);
            picData = (XWPFPictureData) doc.getRelationById(relationId);
        }
...
```

So if the depreciation should really be enforced, this `if..else` must also be used while setting the blipID. But why the depreciation at all?

The apache poi 3.14 version *lol*

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.model.XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTabStop;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTabJc;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordHeaderFooter {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  // the body content
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body:");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum....");

  // create header start
  CTSectPr sectPr = doc.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
  XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(doc, sectPr);

  XWPFHeader header = headerFooterPolicy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = header.getParagraphArray(0);
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);

  CTTabStop tabStop = paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewTabs().addNewTab();
  tabStop.setVal(STTabJc.RIGHT);
  int twipsPerInch =  1440;
  tabStop.setPos(BigInteger.valueOf(6 * twipsPerInch));

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Header:");
  run.addTab();

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  String imgFile="Koala.png";
  XWPFPicture picture = run.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFile), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile, Units.toEMU(50), Units.toEMU(50));
  System.out.println(picture); //XWPFPicture is added
  System.out.println(picture.getPictureData()); //but without access to XWPFPictureData (no blipID)

  String blipID = "";
  for(XWPFPictureData picturedata : header.getAllPackagePictures()) {
   blipID = header.getRelationId(picturedata);
   System.out.println(blipID); //the XWPFPictureData are already there
  }
  picture.getCTPicture().getBlipFill().getBlip().setEmbed(blipID); //now they have a blipID also
  System.out.println(picture.getPictureData());

  // create footer start
  XWPFFooter footer = headerFooterPolicy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = footer.getParagraphArray(0);
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Footer:");


  doc.write(new FileOutputStream("test.docx"));

 }
}
```

---

**Edit Mar 28 2017:**

In `apache poi` version 3.16 Beta 2 this seems to be fixed since the following code works using `apache poi` version 3.16 Beta 2:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.model.XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTabStop;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTabJc;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordHeaderFooter2 {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  // the body content
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body:");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum....");

  // create header start
  CTSectPr sectPr = doc.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
  XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(doc, sectPr);

  XWPFHeader header = headerFooterPolicy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = header.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);

  CTTabStop tabStop = paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewTabs().addNewTab();
  tabStop.setVal(STTabJc.RIGHT);
  int twipsPerInch =  1440;
  tabStop.setPos(BigInteger.valueOf(6 * twipsPerInch));

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Header:");
  run.addTab();

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  String imgFile="Koala.png";
  run.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFile), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile, Units.toEMU(50), Units.toEMU(50));


  // create footer start
  XWPFFooter footer = headerFooterPolicy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Footer:");


  doc.write(new FileOutputStream("test.docx"));

 }
}
```

Comment: Monkeying with low-level XML is always going to be a risky option, as you've got no checks and no unit tests in the project to detect breakages. The "correct" way to go is to contribute a patch back to the project, along with a unit test, which'll provide stable support plus checks against future regressions

Comment: Where i do "Monkeying" with low-level XML here? I'm adding a picture to a run the absolutely normal way. And I expect that this will run the same way whether the run is in a document paragraph or in a header paragraph. But it does not. Why? Shall I really answer this? Or shouldn't the project programmers answer this?

Comment: The CT classes are low-level stuff, and could potentially be removed in a future release (eg one that moves from XMLBeans to JAXP). If you need to use them, ideally you want to wrap them up in a nice usermodel level class and contribute an enhancement patch to POI to provide that.

Comment: The used CT classes have nothing to do with the image in the run. The run is a `XWPFRun`.

Comment: You could also report a bug for the regression that you found, that would make it possible to analyze and fix it. POI is an active project, so you run a good chance of a fix, especially if you can provide a good test-case and if you state that it is a regression from a previous release it will get some priority over other issues.