# add picture in XWPFHeader

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need add a picture in my header (XWPFHeader). When I put the picture in the document (XWPFDocument) works Ok but  it is impossible in the header of the same document.

My code:

```
  header.getParagraphs().get(0).getRuns().get(0).addPicture(imag ,   XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_GIF, rutaLogo, Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(100));
```

I have tried the suggested response but the picture doesn't appear. In the console I can read an error when I convert doc to pdf using Docx4J:

```
         WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(pathDocumentoWord));    
         out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage,out);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097640/add-image-into-a-word-docx-document-header-using-poi-xwpf/35103749#35103749

Comment: See my last comment in the linked answer. Will not work anymore with apache poi 3.14.