# Problem adding image in the header of word document

Tags: java, spring-boot, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm adding a picture in the header of a word document. It shows a frame for the image and says "the image cannot currently be display". If I add text to the header it show the text, and if I add the image in the document body, it also shows the image. So is getting the image and it show text on the header, but no the image.

I'm running out of checkings, can anyone advise with this please?

Thank you!

```
public static void createHeaderAndFotter(XWPFDocument document) throws IOException, BadElementException, InvalidFormatException {

    XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = document.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
    if (headerFooterPolicy == null) headerFooterPolicy = document.createHeaderFooterPolicy();

    File image = new ClassPathResource("/static/images/NIAB_Header.bmp").getFile();
    BufferedImage bimg1 = ImageIO.read(image);
    int width = bimg1.getWidth();
    int height = bimg1.getHeight();
    String imageName= image.getName();

    XWPFHeader header = headerFooterPolicy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

    XWPFParagraph paragraph = header.createParagraph();
//        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

    XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();

    run.addPicture(new FileInputStream(image), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imageName, Units.toEMU(width), Units.toEMU(height));
    run.setText("HEADER"); 
}
```

If I remove the commment on this line and comment the one before, then it adds the image

```
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097640/add-image-into-a-word-docx-document-header-using-poi-xwpf/35103749#35103749 for multiple issues with pictures in header/footer in former apache poi versions.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this too but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe whether this works or not highly depends on `apache poi`version used. There was multiple issues with pictures in header/footer in former `apache poi` versions.

The following is the most minimal working code using  `apache poi 4.0.1`. It is recommend always using the latest stable version.:

Code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

public class CreateWordHeaderWithImage {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

  // the body content
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body...");

  // create header
  XWPFHeader header = doc.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);

  // header's first paragraph
  paragraph = header.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = header.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

  run = paragraph.createRun();

  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("samplePict.jpeg");
  run.addPicture(in, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "samplePict.jpeg", Units.toEMU(100), Units.toEMU(50));
  in.close();  

  run.setText("HEADER"); 

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordHeaderWithImage.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  doc.close();
  out.close();

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I've updated POI to different version including the latest but still doesn't work. I'm sure you are right but somehow it doesn't fix it. What I've done is to include a template in the project with the header and footer. Is working fine now. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: My code example above is complete and works using `apache poi 4.0.1`. So not clear how and why it will not work for you.

Comment: I solved my problem in a different way (more efficient for my project) but I'm going to mark your answer as the code is straight forward and I guess there is a problem with my dependecies. Thank you