# Apache-poi : cannot add image in docx header

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to create a header in an existing docx document with Apache POI (I have tried versions 3.14 and 4.0.1).
But when I open the docx, in the header I am getting this ("we cannot display this image"):

[image]

I am doing this :

```
document = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open("C:\\users\\thomas\\withoutHeader.docx"));
CTSectPr sectPr1 = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(document, sectPr1);

//Header content
CTP ctpHeader = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
CTR ctrHeader = ctpHeader.addNewR();
CTText ctHeader = ctrHeader.addNewT();
String headerText = "This is header";
ctHeader.setStringValue(headerText);
XWPFParagraph headerParagraph = new XWPFParagraph(ctpHeader, document);
XWPFParagraph[] parsHeader = new XWPFParagraph[1];
parsHeader[0] = headerParagraph;
policy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, parsHeader);

//Header image
policy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(document);
XWPFHeader header = policy.getDefaultHeader();
System.out.println(header.getText());
XWPFParagraph paragraph = header.getParagraphArray(0);
if (paragraph == null) paragraph = header.createParagraph();
paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
XWPFRun r = paragraph.createRun();
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\thomas\\dev\\logo.png");
r.addPicture(in, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "C:\\Users\\thomas\\dev\\logo.png", Units.toEMU(100), Units.toEMU(50));
in.close();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\users\\thomas\\withHeader.docx");
document.write(out);
document.close();
out.close();
```

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: `apache poi` version `3.17` and `4.x` should work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097640/add-image-into-a-word-docx-document-header-using-poi-xwpf/35103749#35103749 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54257112/problem-adding-image-in-the-header-of-word-document/54258182#54258182.

Comment: It doesn't work with both. But maybe still a library pb ? I updated my post with all the poi library i have.

Comment: I told you apache poi version 3.17 and 4.x should work. But you are using version 3.14. Also both of my answers show complete code examples and in none of them the usage of the underlying `CT*` classes is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Following complete example works for me using current `apache poi 4.1.1`.

The example opens a `*.docx` template which should not have headers already. Then it adds a default header having text and a `logo.png`.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

public class CreateWordHeaderWithImage {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./Template.docx"));

  XWPFParagraph paragraph;
  XWPFRun run;

  // create header
  XWPFHeader header = doc.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);

  // header's first paragraph
  paragraph = header.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = header.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("This is header "); 

  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("./logo.png");
  run.addPicture(in, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "logo.png", Units.toEMU(100), Units.toEMU(50));
  in.close();  

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordHeaderWithImage.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  doc.close();
  out.close();

 }
}
```

Same code works using `apache poi 3.17` too.